# Proving $\binom{p-1}k = (-1)^k \pmod p$ using fermat's little theorem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Proving $\binom{p-1}k = (-1)^k \pmod p$ using Fermat's little theorem.

Im not sure how to approach this. Though I think we might use an arbitrary number $x$ and create a polynomial with an exponent $p-1$, but I am not sure how.

Comment: Is $p$ a prime?

Answer (score 0):

We know that: $\binom{p}k = \binom{p-1}{k-1} + \binom{p-1}{k}$. Now, if $p$ is a prime then $p | \binom{p}k$. Reduce the first equation modulo $p$ gives:
$$\begin{align}
\binom{p-1}{k} &= -1 \binom{p-1}{k-1}\pmod p &\implies \\
\binom{p-1}{k} &= (-1)^k \binom{p-1}{0}\pmod p &\implies \\
\binom{p-1}{k} &= (-1)^k \pmod p 
\end{align}$$

Comment: using fermats...

Comment: I just offered an alternative approach (which I also think it's quite nice). No need to accept it.

Comment: How did you write $\binom{p-1}{k-1}$ as $\binom{p-1}{0}$?

Comment: @CoolMath200 Actually, I substituted it with $(-1)^{k-1} {{p-1} \choose{0}}$. If it helps, set $f(k) =  {{p-1}\choose{k}} \mod p$. Then the first equation is $f(k) = -f(k-1)$.